# Does SceneKit have something like the SKCropNode?

Tags: ios, crop, scenekit, mask

I want to do a Boolean Intersection between two SCNNodes. I remember that when I use SpriteKit, there is something called the SKCropNode which allows me to show only a part of its childNodes. I'm wondering whether SceneKit has the same thing? Thanks a lot.

(If you are quite familiar with SceneKit and you've never heard about something like that, please just reply NO, thanks.)